# Based on Excel VBA, is it better to create ADODB objects Or to use DOCMD.RUNSQL? Which are the pro & contra?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ado, adodb

As per title, is it better to create an ADODB objects or an access object and Then use DOCMD.runsql? I usually work with either Excel worksheet and access table. Which is the Faster method and which is the most flexible and reliable? There are some specifics pro or contra?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is:

1. ADODB is faster and more reliable, and it probably has the
   functionality you need;
2. The Access Application object has richer functionality if you really
   need it;
3. The Access Application object might (or might not!) allow you to run
   SQL and query objects with embedded VBA.

In more detail...

If you're using DoCmd, you have instantiated a copy of MSAccess.exe as part of your Access Application object - that's quite a lot of memory, and it's going to take a few seconds to start up: not something you want to do for a trivial task.

However, you now have all the Access application object's methods and attributes available - not just DoCmd, you've got all the CurrentDB objects, including the querydefs collection. So if it's a complex task, not just 'run this trivial query', the Access Application object has advantages.

One big disadvantage is that you can't distribute this sheet to users who don't have MSAccess.exe on their workstation: their VBA can't create an instance of the MS-Access application and it's DoCmd methods.

Creating an ADODB object is much faster, and everyone with MS-Office has OLEDB database drivers for MS-Access, even if they don't have the 'Professional' edition of Office or MS-Access on their machine.

Object instantiation is the big performance issue here: ADODB objects and the OLEDB database drivers for MS-Access will also run queries slightly faster than MS-Access.exe, but that's not the performance advantage you'll notice.

Note that the ADODB connection object will give you detailed errors and status information, and you can set timeouts (on the connection, as well as the command object or the recordset object) that protect you against slow queries or failed MS-Access processes.

If you are an experienced developer with a good grasp of event-driven programming and the detailed properties of the latest OLEDB drivers for Access, you *might* be able to get the SQL to run asynchronously - launch the command, hand control back to Excel and let the user carry on working until the ADO objects raise the 'completed' event. So you can run the SQL as a fire-and-forget action if you don't need the data, and you can launch a response in your code with an event procedure when the process is completed - or report errors to the user.

However, if this is about returning data to an Excel table or chart object, the built-in query tools are now (Office 2013) faster than anything you can do in VBA, whether it's DoCmd or ADODB: even with asynchronous ADO, the first chunk of data is always synchronous, and your Excel session is locked by the 'asynchronous' VBA command until it arrives.

Your ADODB objects definitely won't be able to run SQL with embedded VBA commands - neither native VBA nor custom code written in the MS-Access database - and this can catch you by surprise: the `NZ()` function is very common in Jet SQL written within Access, and it won't run if your SQL is called outside the MS-Access environment. Other VBA inclusions are less obvious, with string-handling being a particular source of confusion: [this Stack Overflow answer gives a detailed explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970320/running-sql-through-vba/32975495#32975495). However, I'm not sure that you can run Jet_SQL queries with embedded VBA from the MS-Access application object, either, if it's instantiated in another VBA-enabled application: I've never tried that, and it may well be that you can only run a VBA-encumbered Jet-SQL with an actual user session of MS-Access. **You will need to test that!**

One quick performance tip: is your SQL actually the name of a saved query (A DAO Querydef object) in the MS-Access database? If so, look at running it as an ADODB.Command object rather than executing it as SQL text; or open recordsets (and run 'execute' methods) with the 'adCmdStoredProc' option:

`rst.Open SQL, , , , adCmdStoredProc`

Also, if beginner-to-intermediate developers are reading this in search of answers to related questions, check that your SQL isn't querying an externally-defined linked table or a 'pass-through' query in the MS-Access database: an ADODB object connecting directly to whatever actually hosts the data will run much, much faster.

That's all I can think of for now, and I hope that other Stackers keep adding to this answer so we get a comprehensive list.

Comment: ADO supports SQL elements not supported by Access DAO. For instance, you cannot use `on delete cascade on update cascade` in `alter table` commands. DAO doesn't support some features for non-jet linked tables (MS SQL, Oracle)

Comment: That's true, Sergey, but your comment needs a little expansion: **an ADODB connection supports whatever SQL elements are made visible to it by the database driver** - a subset of whatever SQL elements are supported by the database engine. So your example is true when you're connected to a SQL Server or Oracle DB, but not with MS-Access using the OLEDB 4.0 Jet driver. ADO itself doesn't 'support' elements, it exists to implement whatever is supported by the data engine. And it's annoying that you can't get all this from the Supports method: you have to enumerate Properties collections.

Comment: I was really surprised, but my example was for Jet. I worked on procedure for changing Access database schema by scripts, I was able to enable cascade options by ADO only thru OLEDB 12, Access SQL doesn't have such options in syntax at all , despite database supports them.

Comment: @Segey The inconsistencies in Jet-SQL are extremely annoying: but your information is news to me! I would never have tried that, everyone 'knows' it can't possibly work. Your discovery implies that a Microsoft OLEDB driver developer implemented a parsing layer *in the driver* to generate subqueries for the system tables (or call undocumented functions in the database engine) when it encounters Data Description Language keywords in SQL. Alternatively, Jet-SQL and MS-Access have always had DDL commands, but they are undocumented, non-intuitive, non-standard and *translated* in the OLEDB12 driver